# Gmail API: messages.list suddenly there's a messages error key despite there's a nextPageToken in the prior iteration

Tags: gmail-api

I used to interact with the Gmail API since past year using these tests https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it but now this examples are failing because seems there are more messages but the next iteration is coming empty.

Problem is in this part of the code:

```
while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query,
                                         pageToken=page_token).execute()
      messages.extend(response['messages'])
```

The error is raised when trying to access the response['messages'] as the unique key in the reponse is 'resultSizeEstimate' and is 0. Sounds like the page_token is pointing to a next empty page.

Is someone experiencing this issue as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your last page perfectly contains the last email with that particular query, you will get a `nextPageToken` to a page with a response like this:

```
{
  "resultSizeEstimate": 0
}
```

The easiest way around this is to just add a check if `messages` is part of the response:

```
while 'nextPageToken' in response:
      page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      response = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=query, pageToken=page_token).execute()
      if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
```

Comment: Yep! it is what I have done... However the code was working long time as it is in the example without the necessity to add the condition. That's the weird part and that's what I'm looking for...